# OpenCV - Image histogram value of pixel

Tags: opencv, histogram, skin

What I am doing is trying to implement an Skin Probability Maps algorithm for skin detection in OpenCV.

I've stuck in a place where I should compare SkinHistValue / NonSkinHistValue probability of each pixel with Theta threshold according to http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~icml2002/workshops/MLCV02/MLCV02-Morales.pdf and this tutorial http://www.morethantechnical.com/2013/03/05/skin-detection-with-probability-maps-and-elliptical-boundaries-opencv-wcode/

My problems lies in calculating the coords for hist value:

From the tutorial:

```
calcHist(&nRGB_frame,1,channels,mask,skin_Histogram,2,histSize,ranges,uniform,accumulate);
calcHist(&nRGB_frame,1,channels,~mask,non_skin_Histogram,2,histSize,ranges,uniform,accumulate);
```

Calculates the  histograms. Than i normalize them. 
And after that:

```
for (int i=0; i<nrgb.rows; i++) {
        int gbin = cvRound((nrgb(i)[1] - 0)/range_dist[0] * hist_bins[0]);
        int rbin = cvRound((nrgb(i)[2] - low_range[1])/range_dist[1] * hist_bins[1]);
        float skin_hist_val = skin_Histogram.at<float>(gbin,rbin);
};
```

Where nrgb is my image, and im trying to get skin_hist_value for that. But the gbin and rbin are probably calculated wrong and it throws an exception (i run outside of array?) when it comes to

```
skin_Histogram.at<float>(gbin,rbin);
```

I have totally no idea how to calculate it correctly. Any help?